# Is there a Selenium-Webdriver equivalent command for "click at"?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Looking at documentation for Selenium IDE, I see that it supports the ["click at"](https://selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/api/commands#click-at) function, which is used like this with JavaScript:

```
clickAt('//*[@class="example"]',"10,10")
```

However, in looking at Selenium-Webdriver's [click documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/input_exports_Actions.html#click), I do not see an equivalent for the above.

Is there a Selenium-Webdriver equivalent command to Selenium IDE's "click at" above? How would one translate the above code to Selenium-Webdriver's version of "click at" using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

There are several options, they differ depending on how you lookup `WebElements`.

However they all boil down to:

1. find `WebElement` using given locator
2. run `webElement.click()`

try here -> https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebElement.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I was looking for a way of using a locator in addition to coordinates in order specify an exact location on a web element, not just clicking in the middle of the element. I believe the answer above does not take coordinates into account. Do you know how to take coordinates into account?

Comment: Oh, that's intriguing. Why do you need to click in certain location within element? Maybe you should use more precise selector instead. And to answer your question, I do not know of such method. Despite working with Selenium for over 6 years, I never had the need of using coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it using Javascript:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("el = document.elementFromPoint(x-cordinate, y-cordinate); el.click();");
}
```